# Can't connect my iPad to the localhost of my Mac

Tags: iphone, ipad, network, wifi, webserver

I want to access the `localhost` of my Mac from my iPad. From my Mac, the address is `http://localhost:8888`.

## Through IP address

The Mac and the iPad are connected to the same Wifi network. The `IP` address of the Mac is `10.0.0.58`

On the iPad, I try to access `localhost` with the address

```
http://10.0.0.58:8888
```

but the website never loads (with the error "No response from the server").

## With `.local` address

I also tried to access `localhost` via the name of the Mac. It is `colas.local`.

On the iPad, I try to access `localhost` with the address

```
http://colas.local:8888
```

but the website never loads (with the error "No response from the server").

## My question

What can I do to access `localhost` from the iPad? Note that they are connected with a `USB` cable so it might also be possible like that.

Why don't my attempts work?

Comment: Why port `8888`? Have you tried doing this with just `http://10.0.0.58`?

Also, what happens when you just type `localhost` in your browser on the Mac? What about `localhost:8888`?

Comment: Check whether the built-in firewall is activated and blocking incoming requests. You can find it under System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Firewall.

Comment: With or without 8888 does not change anything. @gunner

Comment: Neither localhost.

Comment: @Lizzan Nope, the firewall is off.

Comment: Which server setup are you using? Built-in, MAMP, other?

Comment: MAMP, yes. I suspect this comes from the Wifi network I am connected to...

Comment: Are you sure it is http not https, i.e.: `https://10.0.0.58:8888`

Comment: It works with `http` when I create a local network between my Mac and the iPad. But I would have liked to do it on the main Wifi network, connected to Internet.

Comment: @Colas Same problem! Can't connect whether with my iPad or iPhone. Tried with the ip, the local name, checked that firewall is off, re-connected to wifi, tried 2 different web servers, nothing! Did you find a solution?